# does length of barcode image change because of barcode text

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I was reading about barcodes, just a general query I came up with:

Does the length of barcode image change because of the text in it?

For eg: will the length of a barcode with 986262 be different than 111111?

Comment: it may depend on the type of barcode. But a regular barcode (3of9 or barcode128 for example) will be of the same length whent he number of characters are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can consider barcodes "monospaced". The only cases for which this isn't true are when a character needs an escape code to be represented.

For example in Code 128B, you need to escape to Code 128A to issue a control character like TAB, or in Code 128A you need to switch temporarily to Code 128B to embed a lowercase alphabetical character.